# Passing the list from one action to another by TempData does not work

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to transfer a list of values by TempData to another action on the same controller, but I get a warning that this page is not working
If I send a value other than the list, there is no problem, and I even made and sent an empty list, but I was faced with this warning again, please help me.

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsjDr.png)

```
        public IActionResult HasabrseeReport(Hesabrsee hesabrsee, int Projectid, int FaraindName
            , String FramDate, String ToDate, int red, int green, int yealoo, int white)
        {
              var fraindList = _context.Hesabrsee.AsEnumerable();

            if (hesabrsee.Projectid != 0)
            {
                fraindList = fraindList.Where(p => p.Projectid == hesabrsee.Projectid);

                TempData["list"] = fraindList.ToList(); 
                return View(fraindList.ToList()); 
            }
}

    public IActionResult PrintReport()
    {
        var a = TempData["list"];
        

        return View();

    }
```

Comment: if (hesabrsee.Projectid != 0) what is this? is this a get action or post?

Comment: `to another action on the same controller` , so how you transfer the action sir?